# scala regex meaning

Tags: regex, scala

i am new to scala and hate regex :D
cuurently i am debuggig a piece of code

```
  def validateReslutions(reslutions: String): Unit = {
    val regex = "(\\d+-\\d+[d,w,m,h,y],?)*"
    if (!reslutions.matches(regex)) {
      throw new Error("no match")
    } else {
      print("matched")
    }
  }
  validateReslutions(reslutions = "(20-1w,100-1w)")
}
```

the problem is it produces no match for this input , so how to correct the regex to match this input

Comment: It is inside parentheses. Are you sure you want the whole string match here? Isn't `findFirstIn` that you want to use? If not, you just need to add `\(` at the start and `\)` at the end. See  [this online demo](https://ideone.com/wwP3K6).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , thank you , it is clear for me now the old regex regex will work only if the input was "20-1w,100-1w" but to include parentheses , "back slash ("and "back slash )" nedded to be added

Comment: I also wanted to note the inappropriate commas in the character class and the possibility to avoid the "escaping hell" using triple quoted string literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `(20-1w,100-1w)` string contains a pair of parentheses at the start and end, and the rest matches with your `(\d+-\d+[d,w,m,h,y],?)*` regex. Since `String#matches` requires a full string match, you get an exception.

Include the parentheses patterns to the regex to avoid the exception:

```scala
def validateReslutions(reslutions: String): Unit = {
    val regex = """\((\d+-\d+[dwmhy],?)*\)"""
    if (!reslutions.matches(regex)) {
        throw new Error("no match")
    } else {
        print("matched")
    }
}
validateReslutions(reslutions = "(20-1w,100-1w)")
// => matched
```

See the [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/wwP3K6).

Note the triple quotes used to define the string literal, inside which you can use single backslashes to define literal backslash chars.

Also, mind the absence of commas in the character class, they match literal commas in the text, they do not mean "or" inside character classes.

Comment: quick question this string "(20-1w100-1w)" was matched although we do need to force , presence

Comment: @MohamedMosȜd Here, you can use a simple trick with a word boundary - `\((\d+-\d+[dwmhy]\b,?)*\)`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jubbAB/1). In a generic case, use something like `\(\d+-\d+[dwmhy](?:,\d+-\d+[dwmhy])*\)` (see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jubbAB/2)).

Comment: would you mind please help the regex to match this string ('20-1w,100-1w')

Comment: @MohamedMosȜd `\('(\d+-\d+[dwmhy]\b,?)*'\)` or `\('?(?:\d+-\d+[dwmhy]\b,?)*'?\)`, I believe, will help. If you need a more precise pattern, that would probably be `\((?:'(?:\d+-\d+[dwmhy]\b,?)*'|(?:\d+-\d+[dwmhy]\b,?)*)\)`.